# How do I explain these bond angles in SF4 and SOF4?

Tags: valence-bond-theory, vsepr-theory

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thionyl_tetrafluoride) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_tetrafluoride) I found that the bond angle between the equatorial $\ce{F}$'s  in $\ce{SF4}$ is less than that in $\ce{SOF4}$. I understand that is because of greater repulsion by lone pair than by double bond.

But the angle between the axial $\ce{F}$'s  in $\ce{SF4}$ is more than that in $\ce{SOF4}$. I am not able to understand why is this so. Shouldn't the lone pair repel more than double bond here too?

Comment: I'd say the effects are too subtle to be explained that easily.

Comment: You are trying to compare 2 different geometries: one with 4 vertices and the other with 5! Of course angles won't match

Comment: @SteffX Try counting again and don't forget about lone pair.

Comment: I suspect that some subtle molecular orbital effects are going on here.  Oxygen has two pairs of pi-symmetry electrons to donate and is tending to pull the fluorines towards a symmetric structure to optimize that interaction.